# log4j logger class name wildcard

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wildcard

Is it possible to specify not package based wildcard, but **logger name based wildcard** in log4j 1.x?

I want something like this:

```
<logger name="*Reporter" >
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ReportFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

[No](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) (see section "Logger Hierarchy"). What you are trying to do is to define a set of loggers which is not possible as every logger has its own name.

The following should mimic what you are trying to achieve:

```
<logger name="Reporter" >
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ReportFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```

In every *Reporter class:

```
public class MyReporter {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("Reporter");

    public MyReporter() {
        logger.debug("foo");
    }
}
```

My gut feeling is that you **really should use packages** instead.